# First if statement always true, but second one is not

Tags: java

I humbly do apologize if this has been asked before.

Here is some code that I have.

```
    int id1 = 1234;
    int id2 = 5678;
    int idPass1 = 123;
    int idPass2 = 456;

    System.out.println("Welcome. Please enter your Employee ID.");
    while(true) {
        int id = input.nextInt();
        //add more if needed
        if(id != id1 || id != id2){
            System.out.println("Employee does not exist. Please try again.");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Please enter your password.");
    while(true){
        int idPass = input.nextInt();
        //add more if needed
        if(idPass != idPass1 || idPass != idPass2){
            System.out.println("Incorrect Password entered. Please try again.");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

As you can see. the 2 if/else statements are exactly the same, except for the variables. The first statement with the IDs, in IntelliJ, says that it is always true. The second statement, with the passwords, does not give me that warning.

How can the first if/else statement always be true if the second if/else statement is exactly the same (minus the variables) and is not always true?

(Scanner was declared prior to this code.)

Comment: What happens if you comment the first while ? It is perhaps simply a bug in IntelliJ.

Comment: both are always true. Not sure, but maybe you only get the message about the first occurrence that triggers it. fix the first statement and check whether you get it for the second

Comment: What happens if you experimentally swap the two while blocks?

Comment: It might detect that the first `if` is always `true` then the `while` will never get skipped then you will never reach the second `if` so it doesn't matter if it is always `true` or not

Comment: Assuming you get the input `1234` for `id` the `if` would pass because `1234 != 5678`. If you instead get the input `5678` it would pass because `5678 != 1234`. If you get anything else, it would still pass for the previous reasons. It's possible the analysis stops at the first instance of this but the second `if` would behave the same

Comment: @Rafalon actually, you're right. The only way to leave the block is if you get an exception, e.g., if the user types in a string.

Comment: Not to solve your problem, but I think that you actually want `if(id != id1 && id != id2)`.

Comment: They seem the same to me. However, if the first `if` is always `true`, then the second `while` loop is never executed. — Just like @Rafalon said

Comment: @vlaz that's right, but even with an exception, the second `while` (and therefore the second `if`) will never get reached :)

Comment: @Rafalon yeah, that's what I meant - if you get an exception, you don't reach the second `if`, therefore, it's not always true. I wasn't clear there but it all comes down to - you're right :)

Comment: Could somebody please protect this question? No additional answers which do not answer the queston are needed anymore, more answers which do answer the question neither.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your `id1` and `id2` are not equal, the expression `(id != id1 || id != id2)`should always be evaluated to true. You probably want to use `&&` to replace `||`. And then your code falls in the first loop, leading to the second expression not evaluated, so no warning.

Comment: Sorry, with all those answers I didn't see yours so I actually ended up answering with the point I had in my comment

Comment: Good answer, I’m not on my computer right now so I can’t check, but I will check later.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why IntelliJ does not tell you anything about the second `if` is because it detects that you can never enter the second `while`.

Indeed, the only way to break out of the first `while` is to have an exception, and even then, you won't enter the second `while`.

Therefore there's no need for IntelliJ to check anything that happens inside this second `while`.

Answer (score 0):

You logic is off, and the `if` statement should *AND* together the two equality checks:

```
if (id != id1 && id != id2) {
    System.out.println("Employee does not exist. Please try again.");
}
```

You may convince yourself of this by rephrasing that you want to block so long as the `id` entered is *not* either `id1` or `id2`, i.e.

```
NOT (id = id1 || id = id2)
```

By DeMorgan's laws, `NOT (p OR q)` becomes `NOT p AND NOT q`.

**Edit:** The reason the second loop never gets hit is trivial, and is because the first loop can never exit.  But the important thing here is understanding DeMorgan's laws.  This type of error comes up often here.

Comment: @Yunnosch, same would apply for the second condition

Comment: You mean `NOT (id == id1 || id == id2)`

Comment: @NicholasK no, it wouldn't. You cannot REACH the second `if`, ergo it cannot be always true.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with your use of the `||` (or). What the program logic is seeing is, "If the id is not equal to the value of id1 **OR** the id is not equal to id2 then this statement is true."

Since you can't have an ID equal to both of those numbers at the same time, then it will always evaluate to true.

-edit-

Your IDE is smart enough to recognize this and will see that you will never be able to exit the first while loop. That means that you will never reach the second if statement, and it will never evaluate at all, positively or negatively.

To fix this issue, utilize the && operator instead to see if they are not equal to either of the ids.

Also, either ID will work with either password because there is nothing that matches the ID up with the ID password

Comment: I edited my answer, but if you change the first if statement to an `&&`, and leave the second one as a `||` you'll see that the warning now shows up on the second if statement. Your IDE is smart enough to recognize this and will see that you will never be able to exit the first while loop. That means that you will never reach the second if statement, and it will never evaluate at all, positively or negatively.

Answer (score 0):

Because the first if is always true and there is no break in the if section, while loop will never end. So may be that's the reason second one is not showing warning.

Try commenting the first while section and see if a warning is shown in the second.

Also, one bug with your code, between two while loop, you should use `input.nextLine()`, because when you enter first input and press enter, first `input.nextLine()` will consume the int but not the new line and if will be passed to second `input.nextLine()`. So to consume new-line have `input.nextLine()` in between two `nextInt()`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the logical OR operator, only one TRUE value is enough to execute the IF block. Your id can be id1, id2 or something else. If id=id1 left side is FALSE and right side is TRUE. If id=id2 left side is TRUE and right side is FALSE. If id is something else both sides are TRUE. In every scenario condition checking ends up with being TRUE. Therefore IF block is always TRUE. You have to modify it as follows;

```
if(id == id1 || id == id2){
    break;
} else {
    System.out.println("Employee does not exist. Please try again.");        
}
```

OR

```
if(id != id1 && id != id2){
    System.out.println("Employee does not exist. Please try again.");
} else {
    break;
}
```

Comment: This explains why the warning occurs for first if. But the question is about why NOT for the second.

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm not sure, but probably your IDE might have stopped evaluating your code at the 1st warning. Correct the ist IF block and then see. However you have to correct both IF blocks to get your thing done.

Comment: Please edit that guess into your answer. While doing so try to make more clear in which way your answer adds any additional insight tp the topic, when compared to the existing, less guessy answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that 
id != id1 || id != id2
will never be false because id1 and id2 values are different and if id == id1 then id can not be equal to id2 , so condition will ever get true in that case
If you fix out that warning then intellij will show you warning in next while loop if condition , and same situation is applied for (idPass != idPass1 || idPass != idPass2) condition also.

Comment: This *does* answer the question, but by now so do some 5 others, older. Please make more obvious what additional insight your answer provides.

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks for the advice , next i will surely keep it in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your static code you can have only this cases in your truth table and they are resolved to true:

```
x y z | x != y | x != z | v
---------------------------
0 0 1 |    0   |    1   | 1
0 1 0 |    1   |    0   | 1
1 0 1 |    1   |    0   | 1
1 1 0 |    0   |    1   | 1
```

Comment: This explains why the warning occurs for first if. But the question is about why NOT for the second.